# I cannot update the List on the button click and change the button class to active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the button from normal to active and also update the list, from the JSON data array. But it is not working.
I tried a bunch of tricks, but it ain't doing anything. I also cannot get to update the state of the button from normal to the CSS active property that is defined in the CSS file.

Can you help me out ?
Thanks.

```js
const list_items=[
    "Record 1",
    "Record 2",
    "Record 3",
    "Record 4",
    "Record 5",
    "Record 6",
    "Record 7",
    "Record 8",
    "Record 9",
    "Record 10",
    "Record 11",
    "Record 12",
    "Record 13",
    "Record 14",
    "Record 15",
    "Record 16",
    "Record 17",
    "Record 18",
    "Record 19",
    "Record 20",
    "Record 21",
    "Record 22",
    "Record 23",
    "Record 24",
    "Record 25",  
];

const list_element = document.getElementById("list");
const pagination_element = document.getElementById("pagination");

var current_page = 1;
var rows = 5;

//design the row items
function displayListOnScreen(items,wrapper,rows_per_page,page){
    wrapper.innerHTML = "";
    page--;     
    
    var start = rows_per_page * page;
    var end = start + rows_per_page;
    var paginatedItems = items.slice(start, end);
    for (var i=0;i<paginatedItems.length;i++){
        let item = paginatedItems[i];

        let item_element = document.createElement("div");
        item_element.classList.add('item');
        item_element.innerText = item;

        wrapper.appendChild(item_element);
    }
}

//design the page numbers 
function paginationPageNumbers(items, wrapper, rows_per_page){
    wrapper.innerHTML="";

    var page_count = Math.ceil(items.length / rows_per_page);
    for (var i=1; i<page_count+1 ; i++){
        let btn = PaginationButton(i, items);
        wrapper.appendChild(btn);
    }
}

function PaginationButton(page, items){
    
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    
    button.innerText = page;
    if(current_page == page) button.classList.add("active");
    
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        current_page = page;

        let current_btn = document.querySelector(".pagenumbers button.active");
        current_btn.classList.remove("active");
        button.classList.add("active");
    })

    return button;
}

displayListOnScreen(list_items,list_element,rows,current_page);
paginationPageNumbers(list_items, pagination_element, rows);
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #feee;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);  
}

main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; 
    
}

main .list{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 768px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 25px;

}

main .list .item{
    padding:15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

}

main .list .item:last-of-type{
    border-bottom: none;
}

main .list .item:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.pagenumbers{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.pagenumbers button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    appearance: none;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline:none;
    cursor: pointer;

    background-color: lightskyblue;

    margin:5px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.pagenumbers button:hover{
    background-color: #10e993;

}

.pagenumbers button:active{
    background-color: #07f848;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Pagination</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>UI5 Pagination</h1>
    </header>
    
    <main>
        <div class="list" id="list"></div>
        <div class="pagenumbers" id="pagination"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, you're just mixing the `.active` selector (`active` class) with the [`:active` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) (unrelated).

Replace `.pagenumbers button:active` with `.pagenumbers button.active` to see the highlight effect on the selected page.

```js
const list_items=[
    "Record 1",
    "Record 2",
    "Record 3",
    "Record 4",
    "Record 5",
    "Record 6",
    "Record 7",
    "Record 8",
    "Record 9",
    "Record 10",
    "Record 11",
    "Record 12",
    "Record 13",
    "Record 14",
    "Record 15",
    "Record 16",
    "Record 17",
    "Record 18",
    "Record 19",
    "Record 20",
    "Record 21",
    "Record 22",
    "Record 23",
    "Record 24",
    "Record 25",  
];

const list_element = document.getElementById("list");
const pagination_element = document.getElementById("pagination");

var current_page = 1;
var rows = 5;

//design the row items
function displayListOnScreen(items,wrapper,rows_per_page,page){
    wrapper.innerHTML = "";
    page--;     
    
    var start = rows_per_page * page;
    var end = start + rows_per_page;
    var paginatedItems = items.slice(start, end);
    for (var i=0;i<paginatedItems.length;i++){
        let item = paginatedItems[i];

        let item_element = document.createElement("div");
        item_element.classList.add('item');
        item_element.innerText = item;

        wrapper.appendChild(item_element);
    }
}

//design the page numbers 
function paginationPageNumbers(items, wrapper, rows_per_page){
    wrapper.innerHTML="";

    var page_count = Math.ceil(items.length / rows_per_page);
    for (var i=1; i<page_count+1 ; i++){
        let btn = PaginationButton(i, items);
        wrapper.appendChild(btn);
    }
}

function PaginationButton(page, items){
    
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    
    button.innerText = page;
    if(current_page == page) button.classList.add("active");
    
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        current_page = page;

        let current_btn = document.querySelector(".pagenumbers button.active");
        current_btn.classList.remove("active");
        button.classList.add("active");
    })

    return button;
}

displayListOnScreen(list_items,list_element,rows,current_page);
paginationPageNumbers(list_items, pagination_element, rows);
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #feee;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);  
}

main{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; 
    
}

main .list{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 768px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 25px;

}

main .list .item{
    padding:15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

}

main .list .item:last-of-type{
    border-bottom: none;
}

main .list .item:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.pagenumbers{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.pagenumbers button {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    appearance: none;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline:none;
    cursor: pointer;

    background-color: lightskyblue;

    margin:5px;
    transition: 0.2s;
    
    color:#fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.pagenumbers button:hover{
    background-color: #10e993;

}

.pagenumbers button.active {
    background-color: #07f848;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Pagination</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>UI5 Pagination</h1>
    </header>
    
    <main>
        <div class="list" id="list"></div>
        <div class="pagenumbers" id="pagination"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```